# Answers about please, please

Tags: infinitive-constructions

I'm pretty sure that an infinitive can be split with "please" in stated requests, maybe for emphasis. For example, "I'm asking you to please study harder"; "I implore you to please shut up". A Japanese English teacher acquaintance was disbelieving that such constructions actually existed let alone were grammatically correct! Of course, the assumption that split infinitives are somehow "grammatically incorrect" is a fallacy, but how about sticking "please" in there? Am I wrong?

Comment: Hard to say, but you are strictly quoting spoken or written beseeches, meant to sound as personal as possible. Therefore, most any construction that sounds colloquial passes, if natural though not flawless. Consider pretty, pretty please with a cherry on top and I'l be your best friend!

Comment: I don't think using the adverb *please* to split an infinitive is any different than using other adverbs to split an infinitive.

Comment: I implore you to please never ever with a cherry on top split infinitives...

Comment: It expresses exasperation, but the form itself is fairly common.

Comment: May I ask what dialect of English do you speak and whether you're a native speaker? I only ask because I find *A Japanese English teacher acquaintance was disbelieving...* to be interesting. Many might avoid using the stative verb *disbelieve* in the progressive and say something like *A Japanese English teacher acquaintance was having a hard time believing...* although here too a stative (have) is in the progressive

Comment: Interesting point, Claire. Yes, I could have said he was "in (a state of) disbelief", but I think "disbelieving" in this context is working as an adjective rather than a present participle, as in "he was a disbelieving person". I'm from Manchester, England. p.s. I believe in your example "believing" is actually a gerund, not a present participle.

Comment: @billiardsshears Most would say the teacher "did not believe that such constructions actually existed..."

Comment: @Barmar, most... possibly, but not everyone, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+please+listen%22) requires some manual filtering to get rid of false positives, but it's clear, even from the first page of results, that "to please listen" occurs regularly in idiomatic English. Similar searches (with quotes) can be carried out for "to please come back", "to please not go", "to please help", etc.